# installing gcc version 4.8.2 in redhat have an error

Tags: c++, gcc

First run ./configure it worked,
then make -j4, it will report 
options.c:11145: error: narrowing conversion of '-0x00000000000000001' from 'int' to 'short unsigned int' inside { }

GMP、MPFR、MPC install successed

cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-504.23.4.el6.x86_64 (mockbuild@x86-029.build.eng.bos.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4-9) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Fri May 29 10:16:43 EDT 2015

file /bin/ls
/bin/ls: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped

lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Description:    Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.6 (Santiago)
Release:    6.6
Codename:   Santiago

Comment: Any specific reason why you are installing it from source? Why not `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"`?

Comment: You can use the Redhat developer toolset for this. I would heavily recommend using that over trying to do this yourself.